# Are these words in continuous tense?

Tags: grammar

Are the words "imagination" and "curiosity" in continuous tense?

Comment: you might want to check this out http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html

Comment: 1. Tenses apply to verbs only.

2. Continuous (or progressive) forms are identifiable by their ending.  
    They all end with -ing. E.g., ask-ing, look-ing, question-ing

Answer (score 2):

"imagination" and "curiosity" are abstract nouns. 
Only a verb can be said **to be having** a continuous tense;  you **will be looking for** a verb with more than one word (compound verb) like these.